# opencv convert black and white to green and blue

Tags: opencv

I have a black and white image and want to convert this to a green and blue image. So black is becoming green and white is becoming blue. How can I do this with openCV?

Comment: Do you have a black and white image, or do you have a grey scale image?

Comment: I have a black and white image, but I am also interested in a solution for greyscale!

Answer (score 3):

You can use your black and white image as mask:

```
Mat blackWhite = ... //image of type CV_8U 

//new green Mat
Mat bgr(blackWhite.size(), CV_8UC3, Scalar(0,255,0));
//set pixels masked by blackWhite to blue
bgr.setTo(Scalar(255,0,0), blackWhite);
```

Comment: Can you give more explanation. please. I am new to image processing and opencv.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `cv2.applyColorMap`?

```
import cv2
import pylab as plt

path = "lena.jpg"

img = cv2.imread(path)[:,:,::-1]
img_g = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
_ = plt.imshow(img_g, cmap='gray')

image_cm = cv2.applyColorMap(img_g, cv2.COLORMAP_SUMMER)
_ = plt.imshow(image_cm)
```

Fig 1. Black & White image (to be strict, this is grayscale)
[image]

Fig 2. Green & Blue image

[image]